# How to use Laravel getRoutes

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

I am trying to get the complete list of route info of my application via `Route::getRoutes()`. The problem is that all property in the `getRoutes` are protected. I can only `var_dump()` or `dd()` it. When I try to access it, it return the error `Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection`.

So, how can I retrieve information out from `getRoutes`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve route name , path etc from getRoutes.

```
$routes = Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routes as $route) {
   // get the route name.  
   echo $route->getName();

   // get the path
   echo $route->getPath();

   // get the action. Which controller method will be called.

   var_dump($route->getAction());
}
```

Comment: Any idea for to filter that for example for only api routes?

Comment: On Laravel 10 we also have $route->uri  as a parameter, so we can list all URIs if needed for example.